# req.body is empty for a form GET request

Tags: html, node.js

For the below form:

```html
<div class = "container center_div" id="loginForm">

            <p> Enter username and password</p>
            <form action = "/authenticate" name="credentials" method="get">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="loginCredentials">Log In</button>

            </form>

        </div>
```

On the backend I have:

```js
app.get("/authenticate", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

However, req.body is empty, I specified:

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

However, it is still empty and I have tried setting `extended:false` but that doesn't fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit a form using a **GET** method, it appends form-data into the URL in name/value pairs. This is why the **req.body** object is empty. Also, this is one of the reasons why you should **NEVER** use a GET method for forms containing sensitive data.

Use a **POST** method, and the req.body object will have data.

Comment: I understand, for non-sensitive data I can access it with `req.params.something`. How do I intercept the response now on the client-side? Normally, I'd use `fetch` but with forms I guess that's done automatically so how to get the response on the client side if succesfully authenticated or not?

Comment: If you need to intercept the response, you'll have to use fetch. The default behaviour is to refresh/redirect to the form url (which will be the same for a POST, or with extra params for a GET)

Comment: But considering authentication, once I check that the credentials are correct I redirect to another page for authenticated users via `res.redirect()`?

Comment: yes, res.redirect('some/url/here') will work.

Comment: But doesn't that mean that a non-authenticated user can also enter that URL and use the authenticated part of the site? @nip

Comment: That's a different issue. You'll need to add private routes in the front-end (which can't be trusted because the user can mess with the code), and middleware to the private api routes with some authorization strategy (this is the most important)

Answer (score -1):

A **GET** method can / should never contain a body. You can pass data using `req.query` or `req.params` but not `req.body`. If you are passing confidential data like passwords etc, you should consider using a **POST** method

Answer (score -2):

The HTTP verb/method is just a literal. It is perfectly possible to use other custom methods (response status codes is the same scenario, is quite common that a service to send back a custom status code, see https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/418).

Notice also that query parameters are always available to send data with any HTTP verb (you can send some data via query parameters and others via body).

So you could send a DELETE request with query parameters in the url and encoded form data (or whatever) in body payload. Depending on the case, that could not be a good idea (for example, some systems, proxies... will not read body from a GET request)

To finalize, by default the HTML form will send all fields encoded in the url as query parameters if the method is GET, or encoded in the payload if the method is POST.

To finalize one more time: sending sensitive information in the URL is not (NOT) a good idea. Web browsers store urls in to the history, recent tabs... Web server tipically log the complete url (including query parameters) among other fields... Please, don't do it, for the sake of the users.