# Returning data to a user from an external API

Tags: node.js, api, express, spotify

i am trying to return the value of my search after using the node-spotify-api package to search for an artist.when i console.log the spotify.search ..... without the function search function wrapped around it i get the values on my terminal..what i want is when a user sends a request to the userrouter routes i want is to display the result to the user..i using postman for testing ..

**This is the controller**

```
const Spotify = require('node-spotify-api');

const spotify = new Spotify({
  id: process.env.ID,
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
});

const search = async (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  spotify.search({ type: 'artist', query: name }).then((response) => {
    res.status(200).send(response.artists);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(400).send(err);
  });
};

module.exports = {
  search,
};

**This is the route**

    const express = require('express');
    
    const searchrouter = express.Router();
    
    const { search } = require('./spotify');
    
    searchrouter.route('/').get(search);
    
    module.exports = searchrouter;
    
    **This is my server.js file**
    
    const express = require('express');
    require('express-async-errors');
    
    const app = express();
    require('dotenv').config();
    
    // built-in path module
    const path = require('path');
    
    // port to be used
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    
    // setup public to serve staticfiles
    
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    
    app.set('port', PORT);
    
    const searchrouter = require('./route');
    
    app.use('/search', searchrouter);
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
    });
    
    app.listen(PORT, (req, res) => {
      console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
    });
    
    [that is my project structure][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Your Code has a bug

Which is

`searchrouter.route('/').get(search);`

You are using a `get request` and still looking for a `req.body`

```
const { name } = req.body;
```

name is going to equal to = undefined

and when this runs

```
spotify.search({ type: 'artist', query: name })
```

it's going to return an empty object or an error

[req.body is empty for a form GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68513966/req-body-is-empty-for-a-form-get-request)

So Your fix is

change your get request to a post

```
searchrouter.route('/').post(search);
```